Unexpected behaviour with IEnumerable
In the code below I am mapping data that I got by paralelly downloading objects from AzureDevOps Rest Api. I noticed some weird bottlenecks in my code when transforming the mapDictionary to to an excel sheet in different module of the codebase. It took forever to make a simple foreach over thousand objects because the references to the mapDictionary are lazy loaded.
private Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<CodeReviewResponse>> MapToCodeReviewRequests(
    IEnumerable<WorkItemBatchResponse> workItemBatchResponses,
    WiqlResponse? workItemRelations)
{
    Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<CodeReviewResponse>> mapDictionary =
        new Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<CodeReviewResponse>>();
    IEnumerable<int>? codeReviewRequestIds = workItemRelations?.workItemRelations
        .Where(y => y.source is not null)
        .Select(x => x.source.id)
        .Distinct();
        
    foreach(int codeReviewId in codeReviewRequestIds)
    {
        var codeReviewResponseIds = workItemRelations?.workItemRelations
            .Where(x => x.source is not null && x.source.id.Equals(codeReviewId))
            .Select(x => x.target.id).ToList();

        if (codeReviewResponseIds is not null && codeReviewResponseIds.Count() > 0)
        {
            mapDictionary[codeReviewId] = workItemBatchResponses
                .SelectMany(x => x.value)
                .Where(x => codeReviewResponseIds.Contains(x.fields.SystemId));
        }
    }
    
    return mapDictionary;
}  

If codeReviewResponseIds is a List of ints (as it is in the example) then my data are not lazy loaded and my iteration over those references are fast, if I store it without the .ToList() then it takes forever to compute them, why?

Because not materializing it means that all operations will be done again and again and again, every time you consume the enumerable. The operations are lazy and only executed when consuming the enumerable.

@knittl I know that, but the point of my thread is to understand why is that hapening, I did not use yield return and those objects were indeed downloaded  and properly loaded in memory before alocating the codeReviewResponseIds.

I think you may not realize that this code is actually enumerating (foreaching):
mapDictionary[codeReviewId] = workItemBatchResponses
.SelectMany(x => x.value)
.Where(x => codeReviewResponseIds.Contains(x.fields.SystemId));

and for every iteration we call codeReviewResponseIds.Contains(x.fields.SystemId) which is enumerating as well.
The issue as mentioned in the comments is that we have Where and Select operations on the Enumerable that execute every time we enumerate it - which in our case are happening for every iteration of the "outer enumeration".
The best way to illustrate is via a short example:
static int _operationsExecuted = 0;

public static bool IsEvenOperation(int number) {
    _operationsExecuted++;
    return number % 2 == 0;
}

public static int MultiPlyBy10Operation(int number) {
    _operationsExecuted++;
    return number * 10;
}

static void Main() {

    IEnumerable<int> itemsToSearch = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000);
    IEnumerable<int> enumerableWithOperations = Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
        .Where(IsEvenOperation)
        .Select(MultiPlyBy10Operation);


    _operationsExecuted = 0;
    // this is really foreach
    List<int> found = itemsToSearch
        .Where(x => enumerableWithOperations.Contains(x))
        .ToList();

    Console.WriteLine(_operationsExecuted); // 14970
    Console.WriteLine(found.Count()); // 5 [20,40,60,80,100]

    _operationsExecuted = 0;
    found = new List<int>();
    foreach (var element in itemsToSearch) {
        if (enumerableWithOperations.Contains(element)) {
            found.Add(element);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(_operationsExecuted); // 14970
    Console.WriteLine(found.Count()); // 5

    _operationsExecuted = 0;
    var materialized = enumerableWithOperations.ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(_operationsExecuted); // 15
    // 10 ops for IsEven
    // 5 ops for MultiplyBy10

    _operationsExecuted = 0;
    found = itemsToSearch
        .Where(x => materialized.Contains(x))
        .ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(_operationsExecuted); // 0
    Console.WriteLine(found.Count()); // 5

}

If we materialize we pay a cost of 15 operations, if we don't we pay 14970. That's mostly a factor of the length of the outer enumeration (1000). The bigger it is the slower it will run.

Whenever you return an IEnumerable<> from a method you run the risk of returning an expensive to compute collection of items.
Your Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<CodeReviewResponse>> is very expensive as it has SelectMany on workItemBatchResponses and then does a codeReviewResponseIds.Contains to match up items. It's O(n^2) complexity.
The simplest solution is for you is to add .ToArray() when you build your dictionary:
mapDictionary[codeReviewId] = workItemBatchResponses
    .SelectMany(x => x.value)
    .Where(x => codeReviewResponseIds.Contains(x.fields.SystemId))
    .ToArray();

That forces an iteration at the time you build the dictionary element.
Alternatively, it might be nicer to refactor your code entirely. It took me forever to figure out exactly what you were doing! I think I got it.
Try this instead:
private Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<CodeReviewResponse>> MapToCodeReviewRequests2(
    IEnumerable<WorkItemBatchResponse> workItemBatchResponses,
    WiqlResponse? workItemRelations)
{
    var query =
        from wir in workItemRelations?.workItemRelations
        where wir.source is not null
        join crr in
            from wibr in workItemBatchResponses
            from x in wibr.value
            select x
                on wir.target.id equals crr.fields.SystemId
        group crr by wir.source;

    return query.ToDictionary(x => x.Key.id, x => x.ToArray().AsEnumerable());
}

Again, though, the .ToArray() is there to force the execution at build time.
